# How to deal with the relative path in spyder

Tags: python, debugging, path, spyder, init

I have an `ImportError` when I run a python file in `spyder` that have `"form .tool import *"`
althought, the `__init__.py` exist in all directory of the package.

I want to run a python file in `spyder` and not with the consol like this `python -m pythonFile.py`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: show code which makes this problem, And show structure of your files and folders.

Comment: do you really use `-m` when you run in console? Normally it needs `python pythonFile.py` without `-m` and `spyder` also runs code without `-m`